# How to bind Signal<Bool, NoError> to enabled property of UIButton in Reactive Cocoa 4

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa

I have a very simple use case for `ReactiveCocoa`. In my setup, I have two `UITextField`s and one `UIButton`.

The button's `enabled` property should only be set to `true` iff both textfields contain at least one character.

I started out creating a `Signal<Bool, NoError>` that emits `true` or `false` depending on the the above mentioned condition.

Now, as far as I understand I somehow need to *bind* the signal (or its values) to the `enabled` property of my button. But I have no clue how to do this and more than an hour of research haven't lead to any results...

**UPDATE:**
From what I understand, this could previously be achieved using the `RAC` macro: `RAC(self.button, enabled) = signal;`, or something along those lines. But that doesn't help me since the macros have been deprecated in RAC 3. My question is basically the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30131492/how-to-implement-a-basic-uitextfield-input-uibutton-action-scenario-using-reac) only for RAC 4 instead of 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using the custom `<~` operator. However, it only works on properties of type `MutableProperty`, so we can't just do the following:

```
let signal: <Bool, NoError> = ...
button.enabled <~ signal
```

Instead, we need to wrap the button's `enabled` property in a `MutableProperty` like so:

```
extension UIButton {
    public var rac_enabled: MutableProperty<Bool> {
        return lazyMutableProperty(self, key: &AssociationKey.text, setter: { self.enabled = $0 }, getter: { self.enabled })
    }
}
```

Note that this implementation depends on this [gist](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/ReactiveTwitterSearch/blob/master/ReactiveTwitterSearch/Util/UIKitExtensions.swift) which was created by [Colin Eberhardt](https://twitter.com/@ColinEberhardt).

Now we can just do:

```
button.rac_enabled <~ signal
```